# mariadb slow count on console but very fast on dbeaver

Tags: mysql, count, mariadb

I have this SQL query that when executing from mariadb console or PHP (Laravel) takes a long time

> SELECT Count(*) AS aggregate
> FROM   (SELECT `paquetes`.`id`,
> `paquetes`.`codigoseguimiento`,
> `paquetes`.`direccionentrega`,
> `paquetes`.`telefono1`,
> `paquetes`.`nombrerecibe`,
> `paquetes`.`nombrequienenvia`,
> `paquetes`.`estado`,
> `paquetes`.`marcadevolucion`,
> `tipos_paquetes`.`nombre` AS `tipo`,
> `paquetes`.`created_at`,
> `paquetes`.`devolucion`,
> `ciudades`.`nombre`       AS `ciudadEntrega`
> FROM   `paquetes`
> LEFT JOIN `tipos_paquetes`
> ON `tipos_paquetes`.`id` = `paquetes`.`tipo`
> LEFT JOIN `ciudades`
> ON `ciudades`.`id` = `paquetes`.`ciudadentrega`
> WHERE  `paquetes`.`created_at` BETWEEN
> "2021-10-17 00:00:00" AND "2021-11-17 23:59:59"
> AND `paquetes`.`estado` != 0
> ORDER  BY `paquetes`.`created_at` DESC) count_row_table

Result:
+-----------+
| aggregate |
+-----------+
|    763141 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (**20.631 sec**)

But if I run the same SQL from DBeaver (**always clearing the query cache**)

[image: Result of DBeaver]

It only takes 1,458 seconds.
What I discovered is that adding a limit 1 to the SQL runs at the same speed as DBeaver in both mariadb console and PHP

> SELECT Count(*) AS aggregate
> FROM   (SELECT `paquetes`.`id`,
> `paquetes`.`codigoseguimiento`,
> `paquetes`.`direccionentrega`,
> `paquetes`.`telefono1`,
> `paquetes`.`nombrerecibe`,
> `paquetes`.`nombrequienenvia`,
> `paquetes`.`estado`,
> `paquetes`.`marcadevolucion`,
> `tipos_paquetes`.`nombre` AS `tipo`,
> `paquetes`.`created_at`,
> `paquetes`.`devolucion`,
> `ciudades`.`nombre`       AS `ciudadEntrega`
> FROM   `paquetes`
> LEFT JOIN `tipos_paquetes`
> ON `tipos_paquetes`.`id` = `paquetes`.`tipo`
> LEFT JOIN `ciudades`
> ON `ciudades`.`id` = `paquetes`.`ciudadentrega`
> WHERE  `paquetes`.`created_at` BETWEEN
> "2021-10-17 00:00:00" AND "2021-11-17 23:59:59"
> AND `paquetes`.`estado` != 0
> ORDER  BY `paquetes`.`created_at` DESC) count_row_table
> **LIMIT  1**;

Result:
+-----------+
| aggregate |
+-----------+
|    763141 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (1.339 sec)

The SQL query is generated automatically by the DataTables library for Laravel, the explains shows:
[image: Explain query result]

But I'm not sure if this is correct or why it happens, there are currently about 8 million records in the table

Edit:
The execution plan for the query without limit 1
[image: Execution plan for query without limit 1]

It seems that it is going through the whole table and not using the index.

The execution plan for the query with limit 1:
[image: Execution plan limit 1]
Apparently I was using the index and it does not go through the whole table

Table indexes:
[image: indexes]

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan?

Comment: @NicoHaase The execution plan for the query without limit 1 returns "Rows 8.017.830" and paquetes(ALL). for the query with limit 1 "Rows - 1.560.142" and paquetes (range)

Edit: It seems that without limit 1 I would not be using the index

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also explain more details from the execution plan, and more details about the tables you are using (like the table structure)

Comment: @NicoHaase Ok, done

Answer (score 0):

This will probably run faster in both places:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aggregate
    FROM  paquetes
    WHERE  paquetes.created_at >= "2021-10-17"
      AND  paquetes.created_at  < "2021-10-17" + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND  paquetes.estado != 0;
```

The `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` was derived from your range, and may be a mistake.

**More**

The Optimizer, in general, has two ways to perform a query -- Use an index, or scan the table.  As a simplified rule, if more than 20% of the rows are needed, it will prefer to simply scan the table; Explain will say "All".  Otherwise, it will tell you which Index it picked.

When using an index, it will bounce between the Index's BTree and the Data's BTree.  Since the Optimizer cannot precisely predict whether this "bouncing" will be faster or slower than simply reading all rows ('table scan') and ignoring the ones that don't meet the Where clause, it will sometimes pick the 'wrong' way to perform the query.

You are probably seeing the results of this "which way?" quandary when you change the date range.

Comment: I tried but it is still slower on the mariaDB console.
The where is not exactly the same as I have in my query, but the execution plan is still the same

Comment: I've been doing other tests and it becomes extremely slow when the explain shows in rows more than 1,000,000 but it is always faster if the query is executed from DBeaver or it is executed with limit 1 as I show in the example

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)...` always delivers exactly 1 row.  Hence, `LIMIT 1` has no effect.

Comment: Add this index:  `INDEX(created_at, estado)`

Comment: I understand that limit 1 should not affect, but if you see the examples it is doing, it is changing the execution plan.

I tried it many times, always clearing the query cache and it always runs faster.

I made the index you mention (created_at, estado) but the result is the same.

Comment: The funny thing is that for some date ranges it goes through a few records and for other ranges it goes through the entire table.

For example between "2021-10-17 00:00:00" and "2021-11-16 15:00:00" traverses 1,465,862 rows, the execution plan shows paquetes (range) and uses the index(created_at,estado)

Comment: but for between "2021-10 -17 00:00:00 " and " 2021-11-17 15:00:00 " or between" 2021-06-15 00:00:00" and "2021-08-14 15:00:00 "runs through 7.998.347 records, the execution plan shows paquetes(all) and does not use any index

Comment: Here I uploaded an example video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFc3dgQ0PrQ
After recording, I tried to execute the query without the "estado" field from the where and the query runs very fast.
The cardinality of the index (created_at, estado) is 660 and the cardinality of the index (created_at) is 145.424

Comment: @Rodrigocn - I added some more.  What is `estado`?  Can it be negative?  Does it have more than 2 values?

Comment: "estado" (state) is a positive value, between 0 and 11

What I did for now was create my own query for the count, because that query is generated automatically by datatables.

The queries were this way and it works faster, Just ignore the left join on the count as it would not affect the results on the paquetes table

Comment: select count(*) as aggregate from `paquetes` where `paquetes`.`created_at` between ? and ? and `paquetes`.`estado` != ? ["2021-10-18 00:00:00","2021-11-18 23:59:59",0]